# Access report truncated

Tags: ms-access, report

Whenever I generate a report in print preview, this happens:

[image]

Before today it would (and should) fit perfectly to the end of the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: New printer driver? New default printer? Seems like Access wants to print it in portrait, but the report is designed for landscape?

Comment: That was my initial thought, so I changed the orientation to portrait, but it produces the same result (albeit in portrait this time).  Otherwise, no - there is no new printer driver / default printer.

Comment: Then check (from report design) the page setup: margins and paper size. Something must have changed there.

Comment: I also did that and absolutely nothing has changed around the page setup.  It was fine yesterday and today it is different.